# String to JComponent

Tags: java, string, swing, jcomponent

I'm using BalloonTip in my code, and I need this constructor:

```
    public TablecellBalloonTip(JTable table, JComponent component, int row, int column, BalloonTipStyle style, Orientation alignment, AttachLocation attachLocation, int horizontalOffset, int verticalOffset, boolean useCloseButton) {
    super(table, component, table.getCellRect(row, column, true), style, alignment, attachLocation, horizontalOffset, verticalOffset, useCloseButton);
    setup(table, row, column);
}
```

In older versions, second parameter was a String and it worked, but not anymore. I need a String into a JComponent then, but I don't know how to.

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender and http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Table-Column.htm

Comment: again: learn the basics of swimming before jumping into the ocean ;-) You seem to have not the slightest idea of what you are doing - go read snoracles swing tutorial!

Comment: hint: the ballontip project comes code examples ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of question is easily answered by reading the javadoc and manual of the API (which I was able to find with a simple Google search, although I've never heard of this API before).

But even without knowing the API, if it now takes a `JComponent`, it's because it's now able to display any kind of component inside the balloon tip. Since you want to simply render some text, using a `JLabel` initialized with your string seems like the obvious solution.